# How to remove all inner divs of a specific parent div?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am doing an web application in asp.net. In my aspx page i have a code snippet attached. Please check that.

```
<div id="lblName" class="name">
   <label id="lbltextName">Name</label>
   <div id="resizeName">
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="lblTitle" class="title">
   <label id="lbltextTitle">Title</label>
   <div id="resizeTitle">
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to delete all the inner divs of particular parent div at a glance or by using class name of all child div.

How can I do That? Please help me.

Comment: `$('#parent').children('div').remove();` But which in your markup is the parent targeted? Improve your question maybe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove all children DIVs, use:

```
$('#lblName').children('div').remove();
```

Now, if not what you are looking for, consider to improve your question...

Answer (score 0):

you can use the .html() method for that

```
$("#lblName").html("");
```

this will clear all contents of lblName div

Comment: Better would be to use directly `.empty()`

Comment: But i don't want to remove the Label Control. I want all the inner div removed from the parent div. How can I do that?

Comment: @ShubhadeepChat `$('#lblName').children('div').remove();` Like i said in comment, maybe you could improve your question and tell us what exactly you are expecting HTML to be after manipulation

Comment: @RazoR because i'm not sure this is the answer OP is looking for. I voted to close question, unclear to me

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks a lot man. How can I mark your comments as answer? Please guide me. So that i can mark it as answer. I am new in here.

Answer (score 0):

Using d3.js 's functions *select()*, *html()*, *remove()* .

```js
d3.select('#lblName')
  .html(divElement => {
    d3.select(divElement)
      .remove();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="lblName" class="name">
   <label id="lbltextName">Name</label>
   <div id="resizeName">
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="lblTitle" class="title">
   <label id="lbltextTitle">Title</label>
   <div id="resizeTitle">
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```